# Generate individuals from OWL class defintion

Tags: owl, ontology, inference

I'm fairly new to ontologies and have the following situation:

Given a class definition, I want to automatically generate individuals based on all possible combinations of a given restriction.

For example:
Let's say a "Pizza" class has the property "hasTopping" which is supposed to be linked to an individual of class "Topping". I want to generate an individual of the class Pizza for each individual existing for a Topping. If there are two Topping individuals, Tomato and Cheese, I want to create one Pizza individual with "hasTopping Tomato" and one with "hasTopping Cheese".

Is there any general way to generate individuals in ontologies like this? (As an alternative to implement it myself.)

Is this "violating" the intent/purpose of ontologies in general? Would this usually be handled in a different way? (I'm not completely familiar with ontologies yet.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard method to do this, so I think you'll have to implement it yourself. The Leigh University Benchmark does something similar, so it might provide you with some ideas: http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/

I don't think this violates the idea behind ontologies at all - seems quite straightforward. There is no best practice for it, so however you choose to implement it will probably be adequate.